# Make asynchronous code to work like synchronous - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am using nodejs

This is my function called createSchema:

```
const createSchema = () => {
  Business.findAll({
    raw: true,
  }).then((data) => {
    data.forEach((client) => {
      postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => {
        Object.keys(postgresDB.models).forEach((currentItem) => {
          postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
        });
        console.log('Postgres schema created');
      }).catch(() => {
      });
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Warning:', err.message);
  });
};
createSchema();
```

I am calling this function, inside this post function

```
exports.createBusiness = (req, res) => {
  const business = {
    name: req.body.name,
    code: req.body.code,
    email: req.body.email,
  };
  Business.create(business)
    .then((rawbusinessData) => {
      createSchema()     // this is the function
        .then(() => { .  // i want to complete createSchema fully then only i want to execute this below stuffs
          const businessData = rawbusinessData.get({ plain: true });
          const loginDetails = {
            username: 'sameer',
            password: encrypt('sameer'),
          };
          const schemaLogin = postgresDB.models.login.schema(businessData.code);
          schemaLogin.create(loginDetails).then((loginData) => {
            console.log('loginData:', loginData);
          });
          res.status(200).send(businessData);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err:', err);
    });
};
```

I am calling the first function inside my second post function called **createBusiness**,

I want to complete the createSchema function fully, then only i need to execute other **then** method()  in my second function called **createBusiness**

See my code, i made a comment which needs to work first,

I tried with async await but not working!

Comment: `return Business.findAll({`. Missing return

Comment: Is `postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();` a synchronous operation or does it return a `Promise` that needs to be resolved before running the code on the bottom?

Comment: it  return a promise, i think so!

Comment: I put return still its not working as i expected. @NeilLunn

Answer (score 2):

You're missing returning Promise's in quite a few places. You need to return all of them:

```
// No "block" implies return
const createSchema = () =>
  Business.findAll({ raw: true})
    .then((data) => 
      // wrap Promise.all and map() instead of forEach()
      Promise.all(
        data.map((client) =>
          postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => 
            // Again wrap Promise.all and map()
            Promise.all(
              Object.keys(postgresDB.models).map((currentItem) => 
                postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync()
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    .then(() => console.log("now I'm done"))
    //.catch((err) => console.log('Warning:', err.message));
```

So mostly wrapping [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to actually return the promises where you are iterating

The other thing is don't overuse blocks `{}`. Simply just return on the arrow function when you only have one thing in there anyway. Optionally drop the `.catch()` and just allow the errors from this function to throw. After you debug then you actually "should" remove that line and allow errors to throw.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but still this code: 

schemaLogin.create(loginDetails).then((loginData) => {
            console.log('loginData:', loginData);
          });

executes first!

Comment: @MohamedSameer You sure? Put a log statement in createSchema too. Maybe it just returns something you're not expecting.

Comment: @MohamedSameer The code you are pointing to comes after the `then()` tacked onto the end of this function in your listing. I just put in a `log` for you so you can copy that one and see for certain when this code is done. I'm presuming everything is a Promise and just returning "every" function call. There's no way anything else fires first. Unless you broke your posted code as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn the message "now I'm done" its not showing on my server.

Comment: @MohamedSameer What message? That is not even in your code. The big problem here is that you just did not understand when you need to return evaluated promises. I certainly don't trust that you magically knew how to do that elsewhere in your code. Don't run any other code. Just run the **one** function you actually asked about. I'm not going to sit here all night an debug your entire program. Test the one function and then work out the rest of your problems separately.

Comment: I am using this two functions only, I exactly using your code, check jsfiddle

Comment: @MohamedSameer No you need to to check **one** function. Now here's your test `createSchema().then(() => console.log("hello"))`. That's it. If "now I'm done" runs before "hello" ( and it will ) then what I can do for you is done. Put the function and that in a file ( with your postgress imports ) and then run it. Work out the rest on your own please. That was the problem you actually asked in your question.

Comment: @MohamedSameer Of course I am. That was the point of putting it there, as to prove to you that all promises being called there are actually complete before any other code continues. That was the question you asked and what I answered. Take off the `catch()` as well. Just copy the code from the answer, don't alter it and test it like I showed you to do. The rest as I keep repeating is a completely separate issue and question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, tour code should work. The issue happend may be because `createSchema()` function is not returning a promise.

```
     const createSchema = () => {
      Business.findAll({
        raw: true,
      }).then((data) => {
        data.forEach((client,index) => {

          postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => {
            Object.keys(postgresDB.models).forEach((currentItem) => {
              postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
               if(index==data.length-1)
                return true;
            });
            console.log('Postgres schema created');
          }).catch(() => {
          });
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Warning:', err.message);
      });
    };
```

Comment: Return promise from createSchema (add return to the start of the method). The code of createSchema is already in the question. Also worth pointing out that async/await will also work once createSchema returns a promise.

Comment: I edited the answer and see whether it works. The idea is to detect the end of loop and return promise. Modify the code accordingly

Comment: Now in my second function, after createSchema(),  then method not working.

Comment: const createSchema = async()=>{} change function to return a promise

Comment: Still the second function executes first, it doesnot waiting for first function to complete full

Comment: can u log before the return on the first function and starting on second code see which log comes first. logging is the best tool to spot such issues.